# Relations between uml diagrams

Tags: c#, uml

I have something like this

```
public class Item
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

what is right type of relationsheeps between them? Dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - `Data` is dependent on `Item`, since it "owns" many `Item`s. This is a form of [aggregation](http://aviadezra.blogspot.de/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html).

This is the arrow you are searching for:

```
         0..*     0..*
| Data | ＜＞―――――――＞ | Item |
```

[image]

Comment: I added a picture. The multiplicity is not deducible from the code. So I left it away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your model means, but here is a version of it in normal UML 2:

[image]

If I were you, I would put a property on both ends of the association and give each one a semantically strong name. For example, `describedItems` and `describingData`. Please see [how to indicate a list of types in UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985491/how-to-indicate-a-list-of-types-in-a-class-diagram/33986115#33986115) and [this answer on association ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686510/conceptual-modelling-is-my-drawing-correct/30686824#30686824).